# Error in value when assigne variable with cells value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim PtDnr As Single   
Dim TxDnr As Single
GrsDnr AsDim  Single
Dim AmntDnr As Single   
Dim Jour As Integer
Dim I As Integer

Jour = 7



PtDnr = 2256.03                   'trhough 2 loops, the amount is correct

PtDnr = 0

For I = 35 To 40
    PtDnr = PtDnr + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, I)
Next
For I = 47 To 54
    PtDnr = PtDnr + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, I)
Next

TxDnr = Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 32) ' This Cell has a Value of 167.11 "
NtDnr = Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 33) ' This Cell Has a value of 2088.92
GrsDnr = TxDnr + NtDnr            ' Give me 2256.03, this amount is correct

AmntDnr = GrsDnr - PtDnr          ' Give me 2.441406E.04 wich is wrong
```

I checked the Cells one by one  and make them with 12 decimals, after the first 2, all are at "0" ex: 167.110000000000
What I do wrong, I pass all night and tried several possibility but cannot figure out.
Thank you for your help

Jean

Comment: Why is `AmntDnr = GrsDnr - PtDnr` wrong? What value are you expecting?

Comment: As I put on comment  GsrDnr = 2256.03 And PtDnr also egal 2256.03 And I verified this 2 values are absolut correct.

Comment: Looks like a floating point error. Basically, round your values and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using data type Double instead of Single.

Although I don't understand how anyone is expected to know what is going wrong if we can not see the values that are getting fed into these calculations.

Comment: Yes of course I tried before to declare these variable as a double in fact initialy I I put them as double. Also I verified que the resultat of the 2 loop are correct and if I make sure also by testing the both variable "            Test1 = PtDnr  result 2256.03  - Test2 = GrsDnr result 2256.03" but I put     AmntDnr = GrsDnr -PtDnr my result is 2.441406E.04. Incredible!

Comment: There must be something in these cells other than what you think there is? `Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 32)` or `Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 33)`

Comment: No, as I said: Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 32) = 167.11

Comment: Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 33) =2088.92 And the total is 2256.03.

Comment: Now when I put: 'MlDnr = Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 41) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 42) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 43) _
'        + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 44) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 45) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 46)
'
'PtDnr = Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 35) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 36) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 37) _
'        + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 38) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 39) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 40) _
'        + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 47) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 48) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 49) _
'        + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 50) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 51) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 52) _
'

Comment: + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 53) + Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 54)                                   TxDnr = Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 32)
NtDnr = Sheets(1).Cells(Jour, 33)
GrsDnr = TxDnr + NtDnr

AmntDnr1 = MlDnr - NtDnr   'give me 0 wich is correct
AmntDnr = GrsDnr - PtDnr   'give me 0 wich is correct                                 apparently I cannot do a For Next with exactly the same cell I have a wrong ansver, not in individual variable but only when a compare them?  AmntDnr = GrsDnr - PtDnr          ' Give me 2.441406E.04 wich is wrong !!! I am lost